# Не получается добавить в проект angular material

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, angular-material, asp-net-core-mvc

Проект AspNet core с Angular CLI: 8.3.26, все работало нормально, но мне нужен еще angular material. При попытке использовать команду **ng add @angular/material**, получаю ошибку **The add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.** Попытка обновить с помощью **ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=WhateverVersionYouAreCurrentlyOn**, даже если я указываю версию 1.7.3, дает ошибку типа **"Используемая вами версия старше стабильной"**. Для меня главное, чтобы Angular material работал. Ответ нужен очень подробный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустить в консоли команду

```
npm i --save @angular/animations@8.2.14 @angular/cdk@8.2.3 @angular/material@8.2.3
```

Comment: Вылезли ошибки типа: @angular/animations@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. - Я попробую установить их сам через npm i --save.Но я смог сделать импорт import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select'; - так что, видимо, сработало.

Comment: посмотрите версию @angular/core в файле package.json, скорее всего она была меньше. в целом, вы можете смело обновить angular пакеты до последней минорной версии.